# How to count the occurrences of a specific string in a text file using C

Tags: c, file-io, counter

I am trying to figure out how to count the number times a specific string "test" occurs in a text file using C programming. I want the the program to display the final count upon completion.

This is the code I have come up with, but it doesn't seem to do to the trick. The count I generate is slightly lower than what is actually present in the text file.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm fairly new to C programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[200];
    char key[] = "test"; // the string I am searching for
    int wordcount = 0;

    ptr_file = fopen("input.txt","r"); // my input text file

    while (fgets(buf,200, ptr_file)!=NULL)
    {
        if((strstr(buf,key)) !=NULL){
            wordcount++;
        }
    }
    fclose(ptr_file);
    printf("%d",wordcount);
}
```

Comment: It compiles for me with one minor warning.  What compiler are you using and what is the error?

Comment: @Dani: Just saying the algorithm is wrong isn't helpful.  I suspect S.S. is assuming that strstr will find undelimited strings and that's the error.

Comment: Leading questions for more correctness issues: what does your implementation do when the search text occurs more than once in a line? What happens if a line has 200 characters or more?

Comment: What happens if the line contains the sequence 'testestestest'? What should happen?

Comment: 1 banana, 2 banana, 3 banana, 4.

Comment: The error I am receiving is: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âstrstrâ.

I would like for the program to count every occurrence and increment the word count in a text file.

Comment: The input file will consist of multiple lines that are a maximum of 200 characters, hence the restriction. So I want my program to go through each line, count the occurrences of the word "test" and increment the counter. I want the program to return the final count.

Comment: use strstr , need #include <string.h>

Comment: @S.S.: note that the message you posted is a warning, not an error. Moreover, it (and any other clarifications) should be edited into the question. Questions should be understandable without reading comments. SO uses a Q&A, not forum, format. Should your program search for words (e.g. it wouldn't match "testing", "attest" or "contestant"), or any occurrence of the substring?

Comment: Just the word "test" by itself. It will not be encapsulated within other words.

Comment: See [Why do I get a warning everytime I use malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230386/) for another question about the same warning.

Comment: @S.S.: again, please edit clarifications into your question rather than posting them as comments. Comments aren't well-suited for discussion.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int wc(char* file_path, char* word){
    FILE *fp;
    int count = 0;
    int ch, len;

    if(NULL==(fp=fopen(file_path, "r")))
        return -1;
    len = strlen(word);
    for(;;){
        int i;
        if(EOF==(ch=fgetc(fp))) break;
        if((char)ch != *word) continue;
        for(i=1;i<len;++i){
            if(EOF==(ch = fgetc(fp))) goto end;
            if((char)ch != word[i]){
                fseek(fp, 1-i, SEEK_CUR);
                goto next;
            }
        }
        ++count;
        next: ;
    }
end:
    fclose(fp);
    return count;
}

int main(){//testestest : count 2
    char key[] = "test"; // the string I am searching for
    int wordcount = 0;

    wordcount = wc("input.txt", key);
    printf("%d",wordcount);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code may work but it sure is a trip back down memory lane to 1980 or thereabouts.

Comment: If you said about  the GOTO,  it is only the UPPER LOOP BREAK and CONTINUE.

Comment: Sometimes I think why this disease has just What.

Comment: @Carey Gregory BTW What is that in 2011?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I wasn't criticizing the use of the goto.  I have no problem with them when used appropriately.  It's just that algorithm looks extremely familiar.  I believe I saw it, or something almost identical to it, in some token parsing code many years ago.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: In 2011 I would simply change his if-statement to something like this:  { char *p = buf; while ((p = strstr(p, key))) { ++wordcount; ++p; } }

Comment: @Carey Gregory, You don't consider the buffer across. Mean age at 1980.5

Comment: I was mistaken, in technique, but rather of being able to use lots of memory is enough to be read the entire file into a buffer,  answer in 2011.

Comment: Because I'm very interested in programming, there is a difference of 30 years and the program was very interested in what.
So really a pity.
The fundamental solution just because it is used a lot of memory on it is not cause other problems.

Answer (score 1):

`strstr` is defined in the string.h header. If you don't include string.h, `strstr` is undeclared in your source file and it winds up implicitly declared to return an int and take unspecified arguments (that is, it's as if it were declared `int strstr()`). This can be problematic when the object file for your program is linked to the standard C library due to potential function signature mismatches, hence the warning.

The solution is simple: make sure you include string.h.

As for the problem of multiple occurrences of a search string in a line, note the first paragraph in the description section of the [`strstr` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr):

> The **strstr()** function finds the first occurrence of the substring *needle* in the string *haystack*. The terminating null bytes ("\0") are not compared.

While you can use `strstr` to find multiple substrings, you'd need to loop over the string, using a different starting location each time. Depending on where you start, it could match previously matched portions of the string (e.g. "testest" would count as 2 matches) or only against unmatched portions (e.g. "testest" would count as 1).

If you wish to count the occurrences of a complete word and not just a substring, `strstr` isn't very useful. One option is to use `strpbrk` or `strcspn` to find word (i.e. alphabetic) characters and `strspn` to find non-word characters. With these, you can find the first character of a word, compare to the search string and, if it matches, test that the next character isn't alphabetic. If it isn't, increment the count; if it is, go to the next word. Alternatively, you can loop over each character and use `isalpha` to distinguish letters from non-letters (hence, beginnings and endings of words).

Another option is to split the input into a list of words, then scan the word list for your search word. [String tokenizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266357/) functions will do this, though they alter the buffer you pass in. You can also use [`fscanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263973/) to read a word at a time from the file. This has the added advantage of correctly handling long lines.

Comment: I added the #include<string.h> and it compiles now.
What would you recommend instead of strstr if I wanted to count the occurrences of a complete word?

And also, thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: It is not implicitly declared to take no arguments; it is implicitly declared to take an undefined set of arguments.